# PHP supports first-class functions, what does it mean

Tags: php, function, first-class-functions

What does this statement mean in `php`,

> PHP supports first-class functions

Would anyone explain briefly, I seems not to understand while reading the documentation.

I would appreciate an example.

Comment: [what is a first class function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function):

> This means the language supports passing functions as arguments to
>   other functions, returning them as the values from other functions,
>   and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures.

Originally you could assign function as strings or arrays to variables:

```
$aFunction = 'someFunctionName';
$aFunction();
$aMethod = [$object, 'someMethodName'];
$aMethod();
```

You might see that in old source. It is an indirect reference to the function/method (by its name). Current PHP provides better ways. You can assign an anonymous function directly to a variable:

```
$aFunction = function(...$arguments) {
  var_dump($arguments);
};
$aFunction();
```

Or implement the magic method '__invoke()' in a class:

```
class A {
  public function __invoke(...$arguments) {
    var_dump($arguments);
  }
}

$aFunction = new A();
$aFunction(1, 2);
```

In PHP 7.4 shortcut function for simple expressions were added:

```
$aFunction = fn(...$arguments) => var_dump($arguments);
$aFunction(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, well explained

Answer (score 2):

It means that PHP functions can be treated as variables.  They can be saved, passed as arguments to functions and so on.

For example:

```
$square = fn(int $a) => $a**2;

echo (fn($func) => $func(3))($square);
```